# Issue with Transaction with same name on Save Points

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am trying to learn transactions in SQL Server.

I begin with deleting data in a Customer table with:

```
Delete from Customer
```

Then I create a the following transaction and have save points with same name:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

 SAVE TRANSACTION SavePoint1
  INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (1, 'Code_1', 'Ramesh')
     INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (2, 'Code_2', 'Suresh')

 SAVE TRANSACTION SavePoint1
  INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (3, 'Code_3', 'Priyanka')
     INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (4, 'Code_4', 'Preety')

 SAVE TRANSACTION SavePoint3
  INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (5, 'Code_5', 'John')
     INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (6, 'Code_6', 'David')

     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SavePoint1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Now I thought that if I have save points with the same name, and I rollback to that save point, in this case SavePoint1, it would rollback to the last transaction with that name. In my case it should insert customers Priyanka and Preety, which are in the last transaction with the name SavePoint1.

But when I select to run all the records after the transaction in my Customer table, it shows the customers Ramesh and Suresh which were in the first batch of the SavePoint1 transaction.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The question for me is why do you have two savepoints with the same name? It makes sense to me that when you try to save to the same name it would just ignore it because that savepoint is already defined. Truthfully that should throw an exception because the savepoint name already exists.

Comment: You are mistaken. You rollback to SavePoint1 and that was last defined just prior to your insert of Priyanka. Therefore, the table has only the first 2 rows at the end of the batch.

Comment: To add to this, there is no useful reason to define a save point as the first statement within a transaction.

Comment: I was just following a online tutorial.. 
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/sql-server-savepoints-transaction/

Comment: Not ever tutorial does a good job of explaining. And this is one of them. It just states that this is possible and shows some code but does not explain what happens after the batch is completed. Generally speaking, the use of save points is rare IME. Remember that a save point is a point in time - rollback to a save point will undo anything that happened AFTER the save point. In this case, that includes the inserts of Priyanka and after.

Comment: But I will take away the save point on my first statement, and create 2:nd and the 5:th statements with the same names, say SavepointX. 
If I then rollback transaction SavepointX, will it roll back to the 2:nd or 5:th statement? 
The tutorial I mentioned seems to say that it will rollback to the last statement with the same name.

Comment: "Seems to say" because that is how you interpret it. But that is incorrect. The red directional arrows are IMO not helpful in that tutorial. Play with the code, add more statements, move the savepoint around, understand the outcome. Consider that tutorial a (not so good) starting point for understanding.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have a savepoint after the begin transaction. Once you rollback to that very first savepoint, you are still in a transaction and you can continue going on with new savepoints etc. Savepoints with the same name are also fine, this might not be apparent in a single batch but it would be very limiting if savepoints with the same name were not allowed in nested procedures.